# difference between had and have/has had

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-perfect

I am just confused about how to use **have/has had**

- David **has had** a nice car.
- David **had** a nice car.

May I know which sentence is correct and why, and *please let me know how to use have/has had.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*David had a nice car* means simply that, at the time of which we are speaking, he was in possession of that car. That would be a natural thing to say.

If we were to say *David has had the measles*, it would mean that he has, in the past, caught that illness (but he may have long since recovered).

So we might say *David has had nice cars [in the past], but I don't think much of his present one.*

Answer (score 0):

"He has had a nice car" is normally interpreted as an experiential perfect.

> The event or state is expressed as an experience which happened at least once, without respect to a particular location in time, and which is repeatable. ([SIL Glossary](https://glossary.sil.org/term/experiential-perfect-aspect)).

We use the past tense when the proposition expressed is no longer true in the present, so "He had a nice car" means he had a nice a car in the past but not now. He probably has a badly-maintained car or no car whatsoever.